# Gliphs not showing up properly on an Ubuntu Rails 4.1 installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-4.1

On my development machine:

```
Windows 8.1
Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.1
Bootstrap 3
```

On my production machine:

```
Ubuntu 12.4
Ruby 2.1.1
Rails 4.1
Bootstrap 3
```

Here's my code:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to my_model, class: 'btn btn-info' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  <% end %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to [:edit, my_model], class: 'btn btn-warning' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
  <% end %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to my_model, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

The gliphs show up fine on my development machine, but not on the production machine. Images attached. Any ideas?

[image: Production Machine]
[image: Development Machine]

## Precompiling:

I forgot to add that I precompile as follows:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

## Inspecting the elements:

Here's what firebug says when I inspected these elements. They are the same:

Firebug inspection for production:

```
<td>
  <a class="btn btn-info" href="/agents/1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Firebug inspection for development:

```
<td>
  <a class="btn btn-info" href="/agents/1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </a>
</td>
```

## Answer:

It looks like I was dealing with a known Rails 4.1 issue. The solution is to:

1. Have the following set in environments/production.rb:

   config.assets.compile = true
2. Precompile assets as follows:

   RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Precompiling the assets will prevent dynamnic asset re-compilation. I tested it and it now works on my ubuntu 4.1 server

Comment: any errors in developer console?

Comment: developer console? The problem is on the production server not the development environment.

Comment: yeah developer console! the one in which you inspect your elements on browser, it's different from your terminal :)

Comment: Are you talking about the Rails console, as in rails c RAILS_ENV=production, or inspecting the elements using my local browser?

Comment: your browsers console where you check for js errors, firebug or just your local browser console which ever you use

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. It shows nothing different between these elements. I am editing my question to add that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a number of issues causing this:

--

**Precompilation**

The primary issue here will *likely* be [precompilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets):

> By default Rails assumes assets have been pre-compiled and will be
>   served as static assets by your web server.

Precompiling Rails assets is the bane of many Heroku-bound apps (I know you're not using Herou), as many people don't factor in their pre-compilation requirements when designing their asset pipeline.

The problem you probably have is your assets are either not precompiled, or are referencing their "dynamic" filenames, rather than their "static" ones

I would personally precompile your assets before deploying to production:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

-

**Fingerprinting**

When you precompile your assets, Rails performs something called [`fingerprinting`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) - basically where Rails will append a hash to the end of the filename

Another issue for many people is they'll reference the "static" filename using something like the following:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.style {
   background: url("your_image.png");
}
```

The problem here is although this will work in development (where assets are referenced statically), you will have a problem in production. To fix this, you'll need to use some of the [Rails CSS pre-processors (SASS)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.style {
   background: asset_url("your_image.png");
}
```

--

**Fix**

In reference to your issue directly, I would say the main problem you're likely not referencing your CSS files correctly, probably with incorrect paths.

I would firstly look at the `developer console` in your browser - this will likely tell you that you don't have the various CSS files available, to which you'll then be able to try precompiling & referencing the glyphs dynamically to see if that will work

Comment: I precompile the assets (please see my edit), so this is not an issue. I'll look into the fingerprinting and report back

Comment: See complete answer in the edit to my question. Precompilation is needed and reading the links you pointed me to helped me find the answer (albeit specific to Rails 4.1 to work around the known issue)